# Run C++ netbeans project without netbeans

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans-7

Well I have been developing an application in C++ with netbeans. Now comes the time that I want to use different tools to measure/test/improve my app, for example "valgrid" or a profiler. Netbeans has created a .o file for every pair of .h and .cpp classe I have plus the main.cpp. How do I link all this to run them from command line? On the run should I be thinking of the external libraries I added? I just need to find the executable and run it from command line.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be looking at writing a [makefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile). Here's a [tutorial](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/).

Comment: To simply link everything into an executable you can use g++ <all your .o> main.cpp

Comment: Well the idea is that netbeans creates multiple makefiles...and the only executable I find is just running something different, from what it is suppose to run!I might look into making a makefile of my own then, or dig in to the makefile of netbeans.

Comment: IDE generated makefiles are often confusing or hard to read. I don't know Netbeans but Eclipse will generate a makefile for Release and one for Debug. I'd recommend you write your own makefile, it's not hard after you get used to it :)

Comment: It seems that it is also the way to go for understanding where everything that you link to is place and etc. I am looking at the release makefile now because I am at the end of this project but I might end up doing it from scratch. Thanx leo ;)